# Using Chebychev Inequality to show a distribution stochastically approaches zero

Tags: statistics, inequality, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1,X_2, \dots$ be independent Bernoulli random variables, $X_i \sim BIN(1,p_i)$ and let
$$Y_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-p_i)/n.$$ Show, using Chebychev inequality, that the sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ converges stochastically to $c=0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

> I am trying to use this as a step in another proof and I know it approaches $0$; just having trouble showing it using the Chebychev inequality. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is $E(Y_n)$? What is $\lim var(Y_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$
\Pr\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\}\le\frac{\operatorname EY_n^2}{\varepsilon^2}
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Using the independence and the fact that $0\le p_i\le 1$,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname EY_n^2
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname E[X_i-p_i]^2\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname E[X_i^2-2X_ip_i+p_i^2]\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(\operatorname EX_i^2-2p_i\operatorname EX_i+p_i^2)\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(p_i(1-p_i)+p_i^2-2p_i^2+p_i^2)\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^np_i(1-p_i)\\
&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(p_i-p_i^2)\\
&\le\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(1-0)\\
&=\frac1n.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\Pr\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\}\le\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2n}\to0
$$
as $n\to\infty$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I was a little confused on the step from taking E[xi^2] to pi(1-pi)+pi^2....could you clarify this?

Comment: nevermind i just figured it out !